# After reinstalling computer Flask does not serve static files anymore

Tags: python, flask, python-3.4

I have a python app based on Flask that seems to run correctly.  After reinstalling my development laptop and not changing anything in my git repository, the Flask app now doesn’t serve static files anymore.  When I start my development server, the app launches and server logs tell me that everything is running okay.  The main HTML of my app is being generated and served correctly, but loading static files (CSS, JS, images, …) does not succeed.  Chrome tells me that the files are all unavailable due to this error: `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

The server log does not indicate anything:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2015 10:15:47] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2015 10:15:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2015 10:15:47] "GET /static/js/vendor.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2015 10:15:48] "GET /static/css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2015 10:15:48] "GET /static/resources/ispot-logo-69x24.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

As you can see, all requests for static files are served without errors and an HTTP `200 OK`.

AFAIK, I have set up the development laptop identically as before.

I’m pretty baffled by this issue because I can’t find any error messages or hints where to look for the problem.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried another browser? What about something like curl?

Comment: I suggest getting one of the static files with curl and looking at the raw response. Make sure there isn't any funny stuff in the file, like something being added to the beginning or end that shouldn't be there.

Comment: what is your `static_folder` on your [application object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-object)?

Comment: @brian-kh Thanks for the hint about curl.  It enabled me to find the cause of the problem.  See my answer below for details.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for the hint about curl.  It enabled me to find the cause of the problem.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint about using `curl` to look at the raw response was golden.  Both of my browsers were hiding the fact that I had configured Flask to use the sendfile mechanism (using `USE_X_SENDFILE = True`).  Only after running a verbose `curl` against the URL I could tell that this was the cause of the problem.  It worked in the production setting because Apache is configured correctly, but the Flask/Werkzeug webserver does not support the sendfile feature.

After setting `USE_X_SENDFILE = False` on my development machine it is now working.  I must have forgotten to check in this config change into the repo so that I didn’t notice the difference to before.